# hg doesn't connect to bitbucket using a custom key

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, ssh-keys

On my computer I have

.ssh/config:

```
Host bitbucket
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User hg
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_pwd
```

.hg/hgrc

```
[paths]
default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/lohoris/varlibs
```

(running OSX 10.6)

I have exactly the same files on a debian server, but while "trying" a shell login works on both:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
conq: logged in as lohoris.

                           You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
                                                                                                   Connection to bitbucket.org closed.
```

mercurial connection only works on my computer, while from the server it refuses to cooperate:

```
lohoris@office:~/www/varlibs$ hg pull
remote: Permission denied (publickey).
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

This is the same message you get when the key is wrong, only it is not wrong of course (as I said, trying a `ssh bitbucket` **does work**).

It *is* likely using the wrong key, since it's not even trying to ask me the passphrase, but I can't fathom *why*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your path, you should use `ssh://bitbucket/lohoris/varlibs`, not `ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/lohoris/varlibs`.

Comment: According to the documentation the user should be hg for mercurial and git for git. See https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket#UsetheSSHprotocolwithBitbucket-RepositoryURLformatsbyconnectionprotocol

Comment: Yes, that's what is in his `~/.ssh/config` file.

Comment: I see. I read your answer out of context. Maybe worth repeating in your answer that his specific configuration of 'User hg' effects his ssh command.

Answer (score 5):

If you get “Permission denied (publickey)”, it just means that the public key required to access and push to the server cannot be found. To get around this you’re going to run the following commands:

```
ssh-agent
ssh-add <full path to your key file>
```

- [Troubleshooting SSH Issues](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Troubleshooting+SSH+Issues)
- [Set up SSH for Git and Mercurial (Mac OSX/Linux)](http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678)

`ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org` also is good and fast ssh-debugger

Comment: Using ssh-agent worked, but that's not exactly what I wanted to do. I noticed now that `hg pull -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_pwd"` works too, so I guess the problem is really that when hg uses ssh it ignores .ssh/config file and goes with the default key anyway. What could I do about that?

Comment: Adding `[ui]
ssh = ssh -C -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_pwd` to `.hg/hgrg` did the trick.